# Filter chain halted as :ensure_valid_accept_media_type rendered or redirected Completed 406 Not Acceptable Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activerecord, api-design

I am building a simple API using Rails 5. I followed this video tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpzIhQBXUQk) which uses the [jsonapi-resources](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources) gem. I went a little further and actually setup some API security using gems.

```rb
# Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'puma'
#gem 'pg'
gem 'jsonapi-resources', '~> 0.7.1.beta2'

# Security
gem 'rack-attack'
gem 'rack-protection'
gem 'secure_headers'
gem 'brakeman'
gem 'rack-cors'

gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-oauth2'
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_token_auth', git: 'git://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth.git'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2"
gem 'omniauth-github'
gem 'omniauth-twitch'
gem 'omniauth-instagram'

gem 'pundit'
gem 'dynamic_sitemaps'
gem 'faker'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
  gem 'better_errors'
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

I have followed the video and other blog posts, and I am getting the following error:

```rb
Started GET "/collections.json" for 14.144.15.10 at 2016-07-19 00:26:03 +0000
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by CollectionsController#index as JSON
Filter chain halted as :ensure_valid_accept_media_type rendered or redirected
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 289ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

And when I visit the index page for Collections (http://mydevapp.com/collections.json) I get:

```
{"errors":[{"title":"Not acceptable","detail":"All requests must use the 'application/vnd.api+json' Accept without media type parameters. This request specified 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'.","code":"406","status":"406"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

So there was never a problem with the API. Because of my limited experience with API's I was simply visiting the page, but since I added the security gems, it only allowed access to the data by making API calls.

SOLUTION: I used [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) as my REST client to make calls to my API, but you can use any that you may like.